# Load ELF binary around an arbitrary initialized memory block

Tags: linux, memory-management, process

I'm working on a project that will require me to load some data into memory at memory addresses determined at runtime and then load an ELF binary into the same address space. I know I can compile the ELF as position-independent, but how can I allocate my memory block and *then* load and run the binary without overwriting the memory block or moving into a different address space?

Comment: Please explain more how the ELF binary is obtained, and what is the process and the program doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Exec replaces the entire memory space and I don't think there's much you can do about that.
But maybe you could use shared memory to share the data between your old and new processes?

Answer (score 1):

Can you compile the ELF binary as a shared library and then dynamically link it into your original process?  The dynamic linker should respect exisiting malloc/mmap memory allocations and not step on them.

Comment: The original process isn't linked to libc, so dynamic linking isn't really an option.

Comment: But you could use `dlopen`, and I would be surprised if the original process is not using `libc`. How was it built? Is it a small program coded in assembler???

Comment: @nosuchthingasstars If you're avoiding built-in libraries, you can always do what they would've done yourself (open the ELF file, and parse it and mmap its segments).  There are libraries for parsing and  ELF files (though they probably use libc primitives too).  As binary file formats go, ELF is reasonably sane so you can even parse the file yourself if you must.