# How to load a program in memory at a different address than it is intended for?

Tags: c, linux, compiler-construction, linker, ld

Generally the user program binaries will be loaded in low address (usually around `0x400000`) in the programs address space which will be specified in the `elf` binary (in the case of linux).

Can we force a user binary to load at a high address, possibly within the `2GB` range of addresses where `libc` or other such libraries are loaded?

I have tried finding a solution on the net but could not find any concrete solution for this.

(I am working on Ubuntu 12.10 64bit OS)

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to make your binary a shared library which will be loaded like libc? This link could be helpful: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html. Also related to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107143/load-elf-binary-around-an-arbitrary-initialized-memory-block

Comment: This thread(http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2010-02/msg00212.html) mentions some gcc options to change the start address of the .text section. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless the binary is position-independent (PIE), this is not possible. Normal (non-PIE) binaries are hard-coded for a particular load address at link time, and during linking, the information necessary for relocating to a different address was already lost.

**Edit:** The above is assuming you're working with an existing binary. If you are producing the binary yourself, you can control the load address that's hard-coded into it with the following link options:

```
-Wl,-Ttext-segment,0x80000000
```

replacing `0x80000000` by your desired address. Certain addresses (such as those reserved for kernel use, typically beginning at 0xc0000000) will not work, and the address must be page-aligned (the last 3 hex digits must be 0).