# How to load module at specific address and execute it in ubuntu?

Tags: linux

I have some x86_64 code, that needs to be loaded at address 0x7ff022234100 and execute it. If this module is loaded and executed correctly it will output in stdout text and I will see the message: "Module was loaded correctly".

How can I do this ? please, help me, I researched everywhere and didn't find solution yet.

I saw something, that I should use -Wl,-Ttext-segment,0x8000000 (my address), but what command should I use in general ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load a program in memory at a different address than it is intended for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234148/how-to-load-a-program-in-memory-at-a-different-address-than-it-is-intended-for)

Comment: You're not providing enough details in your question. Are you talking about source code to be compiled? Or about a binary object file of some sort?